# Add 45 minutes to date

Tags: php

I am attempting to convert two numbers to a time in the format H:i and then add 45 minutes to them as follows:

```
$starthour = 14;
$startmin = 30;
$fullstarttime = date('H:i', $starthour . ':' . $startmin);
$endtime = strtotime('+45 minutes', $fullstarttime);
```

However, this outputs 1800 as $endtime.

$endtime should be 15:15.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should read the docs about [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$endtime = date("H:i",strtotime("+45 minutes",strtotime($fullstarttime)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works great. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the `date` function expects a unix timestamp as second parameter.

To produce a unix timestamp use `mktime`

Answer (score 0):

[`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) needs a timestamp and **not** a string as the second argument. (Read the docs!). You need this:

```
$fullstarttime = strtotime($starthour . ':' . $startmin):
$endtime = strtotime('+45 minutes', $fullstarttime);
```